# What url masking method worked in Javascript disabled browser?

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, mask

I have tried iframing but it doesn't worked in Javascript disabled browser. Anyone please tell me how can I mask an url and still worked in Javascript disabled situation, thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to tell us more, what is your goal, what you tried or some code!

Answer (score 0):

Use POST, rather than GET. Something like this early in the page:

```
    <form action="nextpage" method="post"> 
<input type="hidden" name="parameter1" value="value1" /> 
...etc... 

<a href="javascript:submit();">This page</a> 
</form> 
<form action="otherpage" method="post"> 
<input type="hidden" name="parameter1" value="value1" /> 
...etc... 

<a href="javascript:submit();">That page</a> 
</form>
```

Bit more longwinded, but it will work.